# stat: modification timestamp of a file

Tags: bash, files, timestamps, stat, portability

I use `stat -f %m .bashrc` to get modification time of my .bashrc on osx. But when I run the same command on ubuntu, it spits error:

`stat: cannot read file system information for %m': No such file or directory`

is there a compatible way to achieve this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ubuntu uses the GNU coreutils `stat`, whereas OSX uses the BSD variant.  So on Ubuntu the command is a bit different:

```bash
stat -c %Y .bashrc
```

From `man stat`:

> ```bash
>    -c  --format=FORMAT
>           use the specified FORMAT instead of the default; output  a  new‐
>           line after each use of FORMAT
> ```

and:

> ```bash
>    %Y     time of last data modification, seconds since Epoch
> ```

If you want a portable way to run these regardless of OS, then there are several ways of doing it.  I think I would set a variable one time to the appropriate parameters:

```bash
if uname | grep -q "Darwin"; then
    mod_time_fmt="-f %m"
else
    mod_time_fmt="-c %Y"
fi
```

And then use this value in the `stat` command wherever needed:

```bash
stat $mod_time_fmt .bashrc
```

Comment: Other BSD won't show as Darwin.  It might be better to check the version of `stat` itself. 
 `stat --version |& grep -q GNU` will be true on GNU and false on BSD (`--version` will actually return an error there)

Answer (score 8):

It depends on what you mean by "this".  If you're asking whether there is a portable way to get a file's `mtime` with `stat(1)`, then no, there isn't.  BSD `stat(1)` is different from Linux `stat(1)`.

If you're asking whether there is a portable way to get a file's `mtime`, then yes, you can do that with `perl(1)`:

```
perl -e 'print +(stat $ARGV[0])[9], "\n"' file
```

Answer (score 8):

since the OSX and Ubuntu versions of `stat` have some differences in that OSX `stat` defaults to terse output and Linux `stat` defaults to verbose some hoops would need to be jumped through. One possibility would be to simply use an alias on OSX  would make stat perform the same on both.

If you don't mind setting an alias to force verbose output of `stat` on OSX with `alias stat="stat -x"` then you don't need perl.

`stat .bashrc| grep Modify`  is all you need under Ubuntu. if you set the alias as above it works under [OSX as well](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175325/output-of-stat-on-osx)

Example from Ubuntu  14.04.5 Virtually identical results can be obtained from Ubuntu 16.04

```
   stat .bashrc| grep Modify
Modify: 2014-03-30 23:14:47.658210121 -0500
```

If all you want is the timestamp you can strip the `Modify:` and retain the rest with

`stat .bashrc| grep Modify | cut -c 9-`

Sources:

https://ss64.com/osx/stat.html

[Output of stat on OSX](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175325/output-of-stat-on-osx?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: i think you are missing -x option on OSX.

Comment: @Derry you are correct, sadly I have to rely on research for the OSX bits as I don't have OSX. Corrected answer.